# How to dynamically import react module which is json data

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, module, components

I have module like this

```
const RecyclerView = [
{
    text: 'RecyclerView data',
},
{
    text: 'Codes data',
}

];

export default RecyclerView
```

And when I Import and map the data like below I get Result

recycle RecyclerView data
...

```
import React from "react";
import accordion from "../pages/RecyclerView";
import Home from "./Home"
import TextComponent from "./TextComponent";

export default function DecisionActivity(props) {
    //let data = Contents;

    const {title, hasContent} = props

    if(hasContent){

        //console.log({title});
        //where title is === RecyclerView
        // and hascontent is bool
       
        accordion.map(item=>{
            console.log("recycle ", item.text);
        })

        return <TextComponent text={title}/>
    
    }

     return <Home/> 
      
}
```

I don't wanna use this line
**import accordion from "../pages/RecyclerView";**

as RecyclerView (the file name is dynamic there might be more with different name
that I would get in component at title prop, then I wanna map the Json data to create my dynamic UI from different components...

Could anybody help me in this situation a different solution can also help but the name of file (Like RecyclerView) should be dynamic.

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1):

Using [dynamic imports](https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports) could help you, I don't know what you want to do, so I can't give you an example code, but that article can help you. Just consider that dynamic imports are asynchronous

Comment: O' thanks @KOseare finally I could solve this thing using your link [link](https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports)

Answer (score 0):

````
finally I could solve this thing using [link](https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports) 

```
import(`../pages/${title}.js`)
        .then(obj=>{
            console.log("recycle then1 ", obj);
            let acc = obj.default;
            console.log("recycle then2 ", acc);
            acc.map(item=>{
                console.log("recycle then3 ", item.text);
            })
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log("recycle err ", err);
        });
```
and I got the require result before I did the thing like this but I missed `let acc = obj.default;` this thing
````